# How to put each half of an image on the other half

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need to replace each half of an image with the other half:

Starting with this:

[image: Original]

Ending with this:

[image: Desired]

I have tried to use crop, but I want the image to keep the same dimensions, and this seems to just cut it.

```
im = Image.open("image.png")
w, h = im.size

im = im.crop((0,0,int(w/2),h))

im.paste(im, (int(w/2),0,w,h))

im.save('test.png')
```

Comment: What is your question? What's wrong with your code? Please see [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: My question is how do I get from case 1 to case 2 (putting the half with A at the half with B's location and vice versa).  My code doesn't work because the half moves but the image dimensions don't remain the same. I stated all of this in the question and included images to provide more context...

Comment: Extremely similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74581869/2836621

Comment: If the line down the center is part of the image, it (or at least half of it) should have ended up on the right edge of the "after" image.

Comment: @ThePhoton It's not part of it, my bad I should have made it a dashed line or pointed that out. Though it may come to use later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use [ImageChops.offset](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.offset) to do that very simply:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

# Open image
im = Image.open('...')

# Roll image by half its width in x-direction, and not at all in y-direction
ImageChops.offset(im, xoffset=int(im.width/2), yoffset=0).save('result.png')
```

Other libraries/packages, such as **ImageMagick**, refer to this operation as *"rolling"* an image, because the pixels that roll off one edge roll into the opposite edge.

Here's a little animation showing what it is doing:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### How to rotate the x direction of an image

You are nearly there. You need to keep the left and right portion of the image into two separate variables and then paste them in opposite direction on the original image.

```
from PIL import Image
output_image = 'test.png'
im = Image.open("input.png")
w, h = im.size
left_x = int(w / 2) - 2
right_x = w - left_x
left_portion = im.crop((0, 0, left_x, h))
right_portion = im.crop((right_x, 0, w, h))
im.paste(right_portion, (0, 0, left_x, h))
im.paste(left_portion, (right_x, 0, w, h))
im.save(output_image)
print(f"saved image {output_image}")
```

`input.png`:

[image: input.png]

`output.png`:

[image: test.png]

**Explanation:**

- I used `left_x = int(w / 2) - 2` as to keep the middle border line in the middle. You may change it as it fits to your case.

**References:**

- [Documentation on pillow module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)